# I am new to redux. Does installing thunk needs modification of the existing dispatch or other calls?

Tags: redux

I am new to redux. I am modifying an existing code in redux based aurelia app. I am developing new features which does a rest call on successful return of another rest call. As far as I have researched, many people recommend think for async and sync calls. I need to know that does adding thunk requires significant code change in the existing project like modifying dispatch and other invocations.

Answer (score 0):

> I am developing new features which does a rest call on successful return of another rest call.

I am not sure if you need Redux at all for doing such things. If you are using service like Axios to call API you can easily achieve this.

I would recommend you to go through [this](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/you-might-not-need-redux-be46360cf367) article to better understand if you need redux at all, and for Redux Thunk middle ware [this](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk) official page. It does not require so much change as you are thinking.

Though, I would suggest you to check your approach first, if you need Redux or Middleware at all!